# Significance of missing mass squared?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, mass, nuclear-physics

I understand why one wants to compute missing mass and invariant mass.

Using the missing mass, one can find the missing particle in a reaction channel and with the invariant which means taking the masses of the decay products one is getting the non-final state particle's mass (to get the $\pi_0$ mass you would plot the invariant mass of two photons).

However, in a lot of papers I see people plotting the missing mass squared.

I would just like to know the significance of looking at the squared value. Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: It's best to speak of [_squared missing mass_](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Distributions-of-the-squared-missing-mass-evaluated-from-K-decays-with-one-photon-and_fig1_333475535), to emphasize it's _(missing mass) squared_, not _missing (mass squared)_. Eq. (7) [here](https://www.jlab.org/Hall-B/notes/clas_notes04/2004-008.pdf) shows a missing mass as a square root, so it's more convenient to work with its square.

Comment: Not my briar patch, but certainly $E^2 = (mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2$ (or $E^2 = m^2 + p^2$ using normalized units) comes into play. The decay products of a decay can leave with significant momentum.